# Solving the following PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

The PDE is given as

$$y^2 u_x-xy u_y=x(u-2y)$$

What is the shortest method solving the PDE?

Comment: this type of PDEs is solved using the method of characteristics, in this case by solving the ODE $x'=y^2$, $y'=-xy$, $u'=x(u-2y)$.

Comment: Thank you. How can I decide to which the method is best for a any given question ? Is Characteristic Method best? or Separation of variables? or Method of Change of Coordinates? What is the general logic/viewpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^2 u_x-xy u_y=x(u-2y)$$
$$\frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{du}{x(u-2y)}$$
$\frac{dx}{y^2}=\frac{dy}{-xy}\quad\to\quad xdx+ydy=0\quad\to\quad x^2+y^2=c_1$

$\frac{dy}{-xy}=\frac{du}{x(u-2y)}\quad\to\quad \frac{du}{dy}+\frac{u}{y}-2=0\quad\to\quad yu-y^2=c_2$

General solution on the form of implicite equation, any differentiable function $\Phi$ of two variables :
$$\Phi\left((yu-y^2),(x^2+y^2)\right)=0$$
Or, equivalent explicite form :
$$uy-y^2=f(x^2+y^2)$$

$$u(x,y)=\frac{y^2+f(x^2+y^2)}{y}$$
Any differentiable function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

$y^2u_x-xyu_y=x(u-2y)$

$\dfrac{u_y}{y}-\dfrac{u_x}{x}=\dfrac{2}{y}-\dfrac{u}{y^2}$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{y}$ , letting $y(0)=0$ , we have $\dfrac{y^2}{2}=t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{1}{x}$ , we have $-\dfrac{x^2}{2}=t+x_0=\dfrac{y^2}{2}+x_0$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{2}{y}-\dfrac{u}{y^2}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt t}-\dfrac{u}{2t}$ , we have $u(x,y)=\dfrac{F(x_0)}{\sqrt t}\pm\sqrt{2t}=\dfrac{f\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{y}\pm y$